# how to prove that for any interval I, m*(I)=|I|

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to prove that:

For any interval I, m*(I)=|I|.
The proof is in here (Oxtoby - Measure and Category),

[image: Oxtoby - Thm 3.3]

But I don't follow the details, so I am trying to write my own proof. what do you think?

**Proof:** One direction is obvious so, we need to show that $|I| \le m^*(I)$.
Suppose that $|I| \gt m^*(I)$. Then $|I|- m^*(I) \gt0$. Take $\epsilon = \frac{|I|- m^*(I)}{2}$. Take the cover of $I$ by a sequence of open balls $B_n$ where each $B_n$ has radius $\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$. Then $\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1}|B_n|=|I|+\epsilon$ contradicting the fact that $\epsilon = \frac{|I|- m^*(I)}{2}$.

Thank you,
Shir

Comment: Your proof is incorrect, as $\sum |B_n| = \epsilon\neq |I| + \epsilon$. Cannot see how you can find such a covering of $I$.

Comment: It would be nice if there were a simple proof of this incredibly obvious fact.  Is there one?  The proof in the book looks nasty.